# Definir borde de un uiview por lados en vez de el conjunto. Mejor ver para entender la pregunta

Tags: swift2, swift

Es posible poner un `border-radius` de un `uiview` solo en un lado en `swift`??

Tengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He seleccionado los bordes circulares que quiero quitar, pero no se como aplicar un borde a unos lados si y aotros no

Mi código para la imagen es este:

```
imagen!.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5
imagen!.clipsToBounds = true
```

Mi código para el `uiview` la caja:

```
vista!.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5
vista?.backgroundColor = AppDelegate().getColorCajas()
vista?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
vista?.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

**EDITADO**

He añadido este código que está en la respuesta de @mhergon

```
let radius = 7.5
let pathDos = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: imagen!.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
let maskDos = CAShapeLayer()
maskDos.path = pathDos.CGPath
imagen!.layer.mask = maskDos
```

Pero las imágenes me aparecen cortadas ahora, y el borde sigue saliendo en el lado derecho
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No queda nada claro qué es lo que quieres hacer, ¿puedes explicarlo mejor? Quizás con una imagen...

Comment: Ya he modificado mi pregunta @mhergon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta estos parámetros:

```
let view = UIView()
let radius = 3.0
```

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = path.CGPath
view.layer.mask = mask
```

Lógicamente puedes cambiar las esquinas que quieres redondear a tu parecer.

Comment: He editado mi pregunta, no me funciona bien tu código

Comment: Prueba con la propiedad `maskToBounds` de la `layer`